# Linux create symlink from tmpfs to slow drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, debian, memory

My application creates cache inside my OS drive which is slow so I have mounted tmpfs and created a directory inside it. Then I created a symlink and pointed it to my slow OS drive path where caches are created for read/write.

I want to know if my app does a lot of read/write using the symlink, is it going to affect tmpfs or OS drive performance?

Answer (score 3):

A symlink is really just a file that says "go look over there instead" so no, symlinking to tmpfs has no performance benefit.

You might even argue that there is a performance penalty (albeit so tiny that really, it's negligible) because the system needs to dereference the symlink each time you use it.